# How to add font awesome icon class to google maps labels

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps

I have spent hours looking for a way to add font awesome icon class to google maps label class but i cant find the solution. I have tried gmaps and markerwithlabes plugin but still i can't get it to work. I tried overlays too but they get duplicated while zooming.. Here is a piece of my javascript code

```js
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                           'position': latLng,
                           'icon': markerImage ,
                           'label': {'text': '<i></i>', 'color': "black"},
                           'optimized': false

                       });
```

I need help with this.

Comment: can you get the marker font to change to a custom font? (not just FA, but any)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you could actually insert html into the label. However, it is possible to use iconic fonts like FontAwesome.

When you use an element and style it as a FA icon:

```
<i class="fa-camera-retro"></i>
```

FontAwesome inserts an unicode character to the `:before` pseudoselector of the `i` element:

```
.fa-camera-retro:before {
    content: "\f083";
}
```

So, to achieve the same effect in a marker label, you could declare that same unicode character as the text for the marker label:

```
label:{
   text: String.fromCharCode("0xf083"),
   fontFamily: 'FontAwesome'
}
```

Of course this isn't as intuitive as using FA classnames, but then, again, nobody said it would be straightforward.

I left you a snippet for you to try:

```js
var centerMap={lat:0,lng:-77  },
    zoom=7;
    
function initMap(){
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
   center: centerMap,
   scrollwheel: false,
   zoom: zoom
 });

 var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
    position:map.getCenter(),
    map:map,
    label:{
      text: String.fromCharCode("0xf083"),
      fontFamily: 'FontAwesome'
    }
 });

}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  initMap();
});
```

```css
#map {
width:100%;
height:90vh;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
 <i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i> fa-camera-retro
 
 <div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: You kinda answer my question, but the problem is that my icons are dynamic. generated automatically by php.. access to style attributes is still a challage..